Connecting Planet imagery orders to Google Earth Engine
I am using the various guides available on the Planet website, which I find to be insufficient and often conflicting.
I have a student user account with Planet, maybe thats my issue?
I've setup within GEE using the documentation here https://developers.planet.com/docs/integrations/gee/
I've placed and order on the Planet Explorer,  which is in "My Orders' marked as 'success'
I'm using postman.com to make the request to the Planet order as suggested in the Planet youtube clip https://youtu.be/pVdbvCyQK5Q?feature=shared and using the instructions from below the heading 'The Orders REST URL' on the webpage https://developers.planet.com/docs/integrations/gee/delivery/ .
However I continually get an error
Error: Bad Request
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.
Within Postman.com

and the Body has
{
    "name": "Collie_042024",
    "products": [{
        "item_ids": [
            "item_ids": [
            "20240408_012956_60_24c0",
            "20240408_012958_77_24c0",
            "20240408_013000_94_24c0",
            "20240408_013311_58_24b4",
            "20240408_013313_76_24b4",
            "20240408_013315_93_24b4",
            "20240408_013318_11_24b4",
            "20240408_013320_28_24b4",
            "20240408_013442_65_24c3",
            "20240408_013444_83_24c3",
            "20240408_013447_00_24c3",
            "20240408_013449_17_24c3",
            "20240408_013451_34_24c3",
            "20240408_022210_61_2438",
            "20240408_022212_55_2438",
            "20240408_022214_49_2438",
            "20240408_022216_44_2438",
            "20240408_022218_38_2438",
            "20240408_022602_22_24f3",
            "20240408_022604_46_24f3",
            "20240408_022606_71_24f3",
            "20240408_022608_96_24f3",
            "20240408_022611_21_24f3",
            "20240408_022613_46_24f3",
            "20240408_022722_28_24f9",
            "20240408_022724_52_24f9",
            "20240408_022726_77_24f9",
            "20240408_022729_01_24f9",
            "20240409_013949_62_2429"
        ],
        "item_type": "PSScene",
        "product_bundle": "analytic_8b_sr_udm2"
    }],
    "delivery": {
        "google_earth_engine": {
            "project": "riparain-veg",
            "collection": "Collie_042021_PSS"
        }
    },
    "notifications": {
        "email": true
    }
}

